# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in php/class-style-generator.php

Tags: php, wordpress, fatal-error

I've got the following errors on two sites:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in
>   /home/lanesra2/public_html/wp-content/themes/Lanesra/framework/php/class-style-generator.php:123
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/lanesra2/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286):

I've not logged into the sites for ages, both are built on WordPress as you can see. Any potential changes that could fix it?

Here is the code too:

```
{
            foreach($this->rules as $rule)
            {

                $rule['value'] = str_replace('{{AVIA_BASE_URL}}', AVIA_BASE_URL, $rule['value']);
                $rule['value'] = preg_replace('/(http|https):\/\//', '//', $rule['value']);

                //check if a executing method was passed, if not simply put the string together based on the key and value array
                if(isset($rule['key']) && method_exists($this, $rule['key']) && $rule['value'] != "")
                {
                    $this->output .= $this->$rule['key']($rule)."\n";
                }
                else if($rule['value'] != "")
                {
                    $this->output .= $rule['elements']."{\n".$rule['key'].":".$rule['value'].";\n}\n\n";
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Sounds like `$rule['key']` is not a string. Could it be an integer? What is its value when you get this error?

Answer (score 0):

check that the variable [is a string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-string.php), not just that it is set but specifically that it is a string also.

```
if(is_string($rule['key']) && method_exists($this, $rule['key']) && $rule['value'] != "")
```

## Alternative:

With a slightly shorter write, and one less argument. This **forces** the value to be a string, no matter what; it depends on your code base if this is desirable for you.

```
if(method_exists($this, (string)$rule['key']) && $rule['value'] != "")
```

---

## Please be aware that this answer does not solve the issue that sometimes your function is dealing with non-strings as potential methods.

Comment: Thanks all, 

@martin I don't actually know what the error could be. I'm not a developer by any means and built this site to help a friend.  

Where would I edit this string?

Comment: Do you have any advice for me?